# How do I use the AzureDevOps API to get test results?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-api-management

Is there any way to get the Test results for every test case in a test suite using the ADO API? All I've seen is methods that let you get the result of a test run, but not the result of the last test run of a test case, or the individual results of each test case inside a test run. This could also be a good alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Agustín, Do below answers work? Please check it and kindly let us know the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following API doc to get Results of Test Services - [Results(Get)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: I'm testing that one out, and for some reason it's deleting the project I'm in, therefore returning an error code. I'm using TFS by the way.

So if the endpoint is https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude={detailsToInclude}&api-version=6.0


I'm using: https://servername.companyname.com/port/tfs/Collection/Project/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude={detailsToInclude}&api-version=6.0

But when I get back my response, the url has deleted the project. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you are using TFS, so I find this Rest API: [Results - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get a test result for a test run, which is currently available for Azure DevOps Server 2019. Hope it works for you.